# Remove light ball from reflection in TV

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have created a scene where there is a TV screen on the wall, in the final render there are what I can only describe as "light balls" on the glass material within the tv. (extruded plane with glass texture on it).

The lights are Point lights with a IES node on them. Is there a way to make the "balls" not be there?

[image]

Comment: Try increasing the roughness to a point those ball are not visible and then add clearcoat in the material setting. Might help.

Comment: @Rajjaiswal He says he's got a "glass texture" on it, so I guess he means a _Glass BSDF_ shader. To add the clearcoat he first has to switch to _Principled BSDF_. But that's useless, because then the clearcoat will reflect the light balls. But I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1):

The light balls are the point lights reflected on the glossy surface, the size depends on which radius you have set in the *Point Lamp* properties. Reducing the radius will make the reflection smaller (but presumably the shadows also sharper, I'm not sure about IES lights because I don't use them).

To get completely rid of the reflections (no matter if you're using a *Glass BSDF* or a *Principled BSDF*), select the *Point Lamp* and go to the *Object Properties* tab, there you will find *Visibilty* > *Ray Visibility*. Disable *Glossy* and the light will not show up in reflections.

[image: ray visibility]